# Unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'generator' and 'int'

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

What I want:
I am trying to read a list of 6,000 coordinates (ra, and dec) and for each one of those coordinates they're 78 points around them. I am applying an angle (ang) and then trying to find the new RA and DEC. There seems to be a problem with  z_sq=(x**2 + y**2) because I got the error Unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'generator' and 'int'.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

coords=np.genfromtxt('HETDEX_reg.txt',dtype=None,usecols=(0,1,2),names=      ('ra','dec','ang'))
ra=coords['ra']
dec=coords['dec']
ang=coords['ang']

coords=np.genfromtxt('Ifus_78_base.txt', dtype=None, usecols=(0,1),       names=('xx', 'yy'))
xx=coords['xx']
yy=coords['yy']

for i in range(len(ang)):
    ang_new=360-ang[i]
    x= (xx[j] for j in range(len(xx)))
    y= (yy[j] for j in range(len(yy)))
    z_sq=(x**2 + y**2)
    z=np.sqrt(z_sq)
    x_new=(np.deg2rad(x))
    y_new=(np.deg2rad(y))
    Theta=py.arctan(x_new/y_new)
    Tau=90-ang[i]-Theta
    Tau_rad=np.deg2rad(Tau)
    Delta_Dec=z*py.sin(Tau_rad)
    DEC=dec[i]+Delta_Dec
    Delta_ra=z*py.cos(Tau_rad)
    RA=ra[i]+Delta_ra/(py.cos(DEC/206205))

    print DEC
    print RA
```

I should be getting a new set of RA and DEC 78 times (bc there are 78 x and y points), for each original ra and dec.

Comment: Unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'generator' and 'int' was the error I received.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is in:

```
x= (xx[j] for j in range(len(xx)))
y= (yy[j] for j in range(len(yy)))
z_sq=(x**2 + y**2)
```

try

```
In [29]: x=(j for j in range(10))

In [30]: z=x**2+x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-c8ea7ceba90f> in <module>()
----> 1 z=x**2+x

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'generator' and 'int'

In [31]: x
Out[31]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0xb2b411e4>
```

See the error - `x` is a generator, created by the `()` expression

`x=[j for j in range(10)]` is list (list comprehension), but still does not work.   `x` needs to be an array, something that has a `**` method.

```
In [34]: x=np.array([j for j in range(10)])
In [35]: x**2
Out[35]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```